# How to read a whole file line by line, character by character?

Tags: python, file, loops

I am attempting to read single digit whole numbers separated by a single space from a text file. The code below reads 1 line from the file character by character. I want to iterate over the whole file row by row, char by char. How can this code be amended to do this?

```
string = ''
with open('map.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        string = f.readline()
        row = string.split()
        for character in row:
            if character == '0':
                print('zero')
            elif character == '1':
                print('one')
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need use `string = f.readline()` because you already use `for line in f:` and `line` variable already contains line from your file. Another mistake is `row = string.split()`. By doing this you got an array of strings splited by whitespaces `'abc bbb   ccc' -> ['abc', 'bbb', 'ccc']` not chars. Try to do this:

```
with open('map.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # in every step of for-loop line contains new line from your file
        for char in line:
           # now we start iterating over our line and char now contains chars line(including whitespaces)
           if char == '0':
               print('zero')
           if char == '1':
               print('one')
```

Comment: While this may give an answer to the question, you must provide some context around code snippets. Explain the OP why he has a problem and how your approach solves it.

Comment: @travisp4 if this answer helps you, please mark the answer as right.